# How to get all documents from a collection from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having an issue getting all the documents from a collection. I'm essentially trying to update a subcollection by deleting it and then recreating it with the new data. Here is my function:

```
async deleteIngredientSubCollection(recipeId: string) {
  const collectionReference = collection(
    this.db,
    'recipe',
    recipeId,
    'ingredients'
  );

  let querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionReference);

  querySnapshot.docs.forEach(async (ingredient) => {
    let i = ingredient.data() as Ingredient;

    let ingredientToDeleteReference = doc(
      this.db,
      'recipe',
      recipeId,
      'ingredients',
      i.id
    );
    await deleteDoc(ingredientToDeleteReference);
  });
}
```

The querySnapshot returns no data which I'm assuming is because I am not passing in a query but a collectionReference only.

I have also tried the following:

```
const snapshot = this.db.collection('ingredients').get();
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

And the error I recieve is: `Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore.'`. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add `getDocs` function?

Comment: Yes I am currently using it to get the documents from the collection

Comment: I mean add code inside `getDocs` function

Comment: @DrashtiKheni `getDocs` is a function from the Firestore API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-9_6

Comment: The code in your first snippet looks good to me. So if the `querySnapshot` you get is empty, it probably means there are really no documents at that path. Did you `console.log("'"+recipeId+"'")` to see if it matches an actual collection in your database?

Comment: Yeah I did and it does match the respective collection which is why this is confusing.

Comment: Nevermind I found the issue. The first collection is recipes and not recipe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Frank Van Puffelen mentioned, `Error Property 'collection' does not exist on type 'Firestore.'` can be  caused due to the querySnapshot received is empty, it probably means there are really no documents at that path. We can check this using `console.log("'"+recipeId+"'")`to see if it matches an actual collection in the database.

Refer to document [Firebase Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) which mentions, If there is no document at the location referenced by docRef, the resulting document will be empty and calling exists on it will return false.

@Damien Garlinge updated, this issue is resolved, by correcting the collection name from recipe to recipes.